# Android : Is there is anyway to fetch logined user "PASSWORD"?

Tags: passwords

Actually i am trying to sync all my data to my salesforce Account. And i have used batching code to do sync:-
             http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2010/06/retrieving-all-records-with-errors-from-a-bulk-api-job.html

I used this type of code. And used RestConnection, so i have to fetch logined user "password". i couldn't able to do. please anyone suggest me. I am using default salesforce login page for user login.

Comment: You cannot get user password. Do you have access to session id?

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce.com doesn't store passwords. It stores hashes of passwords, which are computed values that can't be traced back to the original value. Each login attempt has the incoming password hashed and compared to the stored hash value, allowing login only if they match. These hashes are not available outside the system platform, so there is no way to retrieve them (and you couldn't use the hash anyways, since it doesn't hint at what the original value was).